# Radare using `pd` without the call graph lines?

Tags: radare2

If I run `pd` I get something like this,

```
[0x00400540]> pd @ main + 4
            0x0040064a      4883ec20       sub rsp, 0x20
            0x0040064e      897dec         mov dword [rbp - 0x14], edi
            0x00400651      488975e0       mov qword [rbp - 0x20], rsi
            0x00400655      837dec01       cmp dword [rbp - 0x14], 1   ; [0x1:4]=-1 ; 1
        ,=< 0x00400659      7f11           jg 0x40066c
        |   0x0040065b      bf70074000     mov edi, str.Usage_echo__string ; 0x400770 ; "Usage echo <string>"
        |   0x00400660      e89bfeffff     call sym.imp.puts
        |   0x00400665      b800000000     mov eax, 0
       ,==< 0x0040066a      eb64           jmp 0x4006d0
       |`-> 0x0040066c      488b45e0       mov rax, qword [rbp - 0x20]
```

Generally speaking the lines that show where the jumps are going on the left are awesome. But for the purpose of copying and pasting not so much. How can I disable them? Or how can I hide those lines? I tried a few different things but no luck.

Comment: You may also want to try the `VVV` command, this is much nicer to look at.

Comment: @perror I use that all the time `V` (and then I hit space). What's the difference between `VV` and `VVV`? Where is `VV` documented?

Comment: Well, I do not know the difference between `VV` and `VVV`, in fact this is a quite good question. :-)

Comment: @perror I don't think `VVV` exists. The top shows `[0x00400646]> VV @ main` as it does with `VVVV`

Comment: Ah, so I did type an extra `V` for nothing for ages!

Comment: @perror no if you type the third V inside the first VV you get the graph of xrefs :)  try s entry0 VV then V you will see the init() , fini() and main() nodes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those lines can be disables via `r2` option namely by:

```
e asm.lines=false
```

after that, they no longer appear in `pd`.

Comment: Very cool! Thanks a ton. I was thinking it'd be mentioned in `p?` I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 4):

well pawel beat me but this shows how to strip some more noise

```
C:\Windows\system32>radare2  calc.exe
[0x01012d6c]> af
[0x01012d6c]> pd 10 @ $$+0x4b
|       ,=< 0x01012db7      0f8538b00100   jne 0x102ddf5
|       |   0x01012dbd      33f6           xor esi, esi
|       |   0x01012dbf      46             inc esi
|       |      ; JMP XREF from 0x0102ddfe (entry0)
|       |   0x01012dc0      a194410501     mov eax, dword [0x1054194]  ; [0x1054194:4]=0
|       |   0x01012dc5      3bc6           cmp eax, esi
|      ,==< 0x01012dc7      0f8446b00100   je 0x102de13
|      ||   0x01012dcd      a194410501     mov eax, dword [0x1054194]  ; [0x1054194:4]=0
|      ||   0x01012dd2      85c0           test eax, eax
|     ,===< 0x01012dd4      0f85e54e0000   jne 0x1017cbf
|     |||   0x01012dda      893594410501   mov dword [0x1054194], esi  ; [0x1054194:4]=0


[0x01012d6c]> e asm.lines=false <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
[0x01012d6c]> e asm.comments =false <<<<<<<<<<<
[0x01012d6c]> e asm.cmtright =false <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
[0x01012d6c]> e asm.fcnlines =false <<<<<<<<<<<<<


[0x01012d6c]> pd 10 @ $$+0x4b
0x01012db7      0f8538b00100   jne 0x102ddf5
0x01012dbd      33f6           xor esi, esi
0x01012dbf      46             inc esi
0x01012dc0      a194410501     mov eax, dword [0x1054194]
0x01012dc5      3bc6           cmp eax, esi
0x01012dc7      0f8446b00100   je 0x102de13
0x01012dcd      a194410501     mov eax, dword [0x1054194]
0x01012dd2      85c0           test eax, eax
0x01012dd4      0f85e54e0000   jne 0x1017cbf
0x01012dda      893594410501   mov dword [0x1054194], esi
[0x01012d6c]
```

and to remove the bytes use **e asm.bytes = false**

Comment: this is a nice one!